# How volatile variable work with the other fields?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

There is a method which is initializing three variables in a sequence :

```
 public class Counter implements Runnable{
     private int a;
     private int b;
     private volatile int c;

    //Other code in class goes here

    private void incrementCounter(int i){
      a=10+i;
      b=11+i;
      c=12+i;
     //some other code
     }

   }
```

The incrementCounter(int i) method is called by a thread, after the intialization of c variable, what will be the value of a,b and c in main memory and why ?

Comment: Variables delcared as volatile have a special treatment when applying operations over them. The instructions that read/modify the variable are sorted, so 2 or more operations cannot happen at the same time. In your example, the value of c will be the one applied by the last applying thread (in the case you are sharing this runnable object among multiple threads)

Comment: There is no "main memory" in Java.  Of course there is main memory in most computer architectures, but because of Java's "run anywhere" promise, the best way to understand Java is to understand it in terms of the JVM abstraction.  In those terms, your question about the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` becomes, "What will be the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` _as seen by other threads?_"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reason about visibility and ordering guarantees of the values of certain fields in terms of the Java Memory Model.

I'll assume that your question was meant to ask *"What guarantees do I have for the values of `a`, `b` and `c` as observed by other threads?"*

In this case, in order to get a benefit out of the `volatile` semantics, you need to have a `volatile` read in another thread that sees a specific `volatile` write. If that happens, the `volatile` read *synchronizes-with* that `volatile` write which *happens-before* the read, and the reading thread is guaranteed to see values for `a` and `b` no older than the values written in the thread where the observed value for `c` was written.

*P.S. When I say "no older", I am being informal, because the JMM goes to great lengths to avoid global time ordering of all actions. If we want to be formal, we can use the synchronization order, and define "no older" as not made visible by a `volatile` write coming in the synchronization order before the one observed*.

Comment: Is it really garunteed that *"values for `a` and `b` no older than the values written in the thread where the observed value for `c`"*?  Is the JVM required to "flush" non-volatile values before it writes a `volatile` one?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes. In theory, you can conform to the JMM even if you don't "flush" stores when a `volatile` store occurs. You still need to make sure that the `volatile` store is not reordered with previous loads and stores, and you need to make sure that these previous stores are "flushed" along whenever the `volatile` store is "flushed" before some subsequent `volatile` load. That probably doesn't make much sense, as usually `volatile` loads happen much more often. See http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html for further (grueling) details.

Comment: Ah! Got it. Page 558. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jls-7-mr3-fullv-oth-JSpec/JLS-JavaSE7-Full.pdf?AuthParam=1460039405_77f1600aca6d570f7b5ec018a3b0820d  Its defined using the concept of *happens-before*. A volatile write happens before every subsiquent volatile read.  Transitivly non-volatile writes must appear to have happened before that.  Well I learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

What *will* happen depends on the hardware platform and the JVM implementation.  What *must* happen is specified by the the Java Language Specification (JLS).

The JLS says that some other thread U will be able to see all three updates *when thread U reads `c`.*

More specifically, the JLS says an update to the `volatile c` in thread T "synchronizes with" a read of `c` in thread U.  "Synchronizes with" means that everything that happened in thread T before T updated `c` must become visible to thread U when thread U subsequently reads `c`.

---

Note:  The "synchronizes with" also goes by the name "happens before relationship", and that sometimes confuses new programmers.  When somebody says, "An update of `c` in one thread *happens before* a read of `c` in another thread," then the newbie thinks that it means, "My thread T will update `c` before my thread U reads it."

"Happens before" does not mean that at all.  It only means that *IF* the update *actually* happens before the read, then...

When thread T and thread U both reach for `c` without any controls, that's called a *data race*, and if the correct outcome of your program depends on which thread wins the race, then its up to you to use some synchronization means to insure that the right thread wins.

Comment: Actually the *happens-before* and *synchronizes-with* relations are not equivalent, according to the JMM. If action A *synchronizes-with* action B, A *happens-before* B. However if C *happens-before* D, C doesn't necessarily *synchronize-with* D. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

Answer (score 1):

In short: The happens-before relationship created through a volatile read of a volatile write ensures that whoever reads the value of `c` will also observe the changes to `a` and `b`.

> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field. [...] If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

> [...] because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.
>
> [...]
>
> Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors[.]

https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

> What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

> Writing to a volatile field has the same memory effect as a monitor release, and reading from a volatile field has the same memory effect as a monitor acquire. In effect, because the new memory model places stricter constraints on reordering of volatile field accesses with other field accesses, volatile or not, anything that was visible to thread A when it writes to volatile field f becomes visible to thread B when it reads f.

[https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization)

Same page goes on to construct an example very much like your own:

```
class VolatileExample {
  int x = 0;
  volatile boolean v = false;
  public void writer() {
    x = 42;
    v = true;
  }

  public void reader() {
    if (v == true) {
      //uses x - guaranteed to see 42.
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, interesting pitfalls to be cautious about:

https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#pitfall-release-order-wrong

Answer (score -1):

> incrementCounter(int i) method is called by a thread, after the
>   intialization of c variable, what will be the value of a,b and c in
>   main memory and why?

I would rephrase your question as what would be the values of a,b and c as seen by Thread B after Thread A has completed its execution.

As per the below quote from [JCIP](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&lpg=PA39&vq=volatile%20variables%20can%20only%20guarantee%20visibility.&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q=visibility%20effects%20of%20volatile%20variables%20extend%20beyond%20the%20value&f=false), Thread B would see the updated values for both `a` and `b` as well along with `c`, but it comes with a caution -

> The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value of the
>   volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable. So from a memory visibility perspective, writing a volatile variable is like exiting a synchronized block and reading a volatile variable is like entering a synchronized block.

But it subsequently goes on saying that,

> However, we do not recommend relying too heavily on volatile variables for visibility; code that relies on volatile variables for visibility of arbitrary state is more fragile and harder to understand than code that uses locking.

**UPDATE:** Removed the statements regarding atomicity of volatile variables as per Ralf's findings. Will revisit that section after doing some homework on the change history.

Comment: Your statement about atomicity is incorrect. The Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) states: "_Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables)._"

Comment: @Ralf Infact, that is a good link and thanks for pointing it out. I think it might have got changed in the later versions of JVM (after the book got published). _Removed the statement regarding atomicity regarding volatile variables for now_. I will check the history regarding this change and will either update the post or leave it as it is :)

Comment: With the above changes, I hope folks might consider withdraw the down-votes if it looks ok now :-)

Comment: The change you might be thinking of was done with Java 5, I would guess. The memory model with regards to volatile changed in that version. Inter alia Java 5 is the first version you can make double-checked locking work with the help of `volatile`.

Comment: The last paragraph you are quoting, cautioning people to rely on visibility through volatile variables, does so purely because of complexity. The programmer has to adhere to a strict "access protocol" that cannot be technically enforced to make it work. It is not that the memory model might fail on the "happens before" guarantee.

Comment: @Ralf That is true, though. Not that the happens-before doesn't guarantee the visibility but not a good practice to follow. And regarding when the change was done, I suspect the change might have been done in Java 1.6, bcos JCIP got released in 2006 and java 1.6 happened in the same year. Will continue the search to see the reason behind it anyways.